# How to convert array of date integers to `datenum`objects in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, matlab-figure

I have a bunch of date integers like this:

```
dates_array = [20060828 ,20060831 , 20060901];
```

And, I want to use them as the x axis of a plot.  So, I try to convert them like so:

```
datecells = [];
for datecell=dates_array
    display(datecell)
    dn = datenum(char(datecell), 'YYYYmmdd');
    datecells = [datecells, dn];
end
```

I understand from [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/215759-plotting-dates-on-x-axis) that these `dn`s are supposed to be number of days.  That's fine.  But when I print out the `datecells` variable here's what I get, and I don't know why:

```
>> datecells

datecells =

      736696      736696      736696
```

Why is it showing the same number of days for all three of these elements?

Comment: Datecell is not cell, it s array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the three-arg `datenum` syntax, after modifying `dates_array` to extract the year/month/day components.

```
% use a combination of MOD and floored division to extract
% year-month-day components
ymd = floor(bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@mod, dates_array, ...
    [1e8; 1e4; 1e2]), [1e4; 1e2; 1]));
% ymd is now a matrix where the 1st row is year, 2nd row is
% month, and 3rd row is day of month
dates = datenum(ymd(1,:), ymd(2,:), ymd(3,:));
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty cell array is defined as follows:

```
datecells={};
```

Now, convert each element to a format and add it to the end of cell.

```
formatOut = 'dd mmm yyyy';
for i=1:3
     dt = datestr(datenum(char(dateArray[i]), 'YYYYmmdd'),formatOut);
     datecells(end+1)= dt
end
```

I havent tested the code.